# Random animation of object in windows phone

Tags: c#, xaml, animation, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.1

I'm working on random animation of object similar to the mole and hammer game for phones but not using thirds in C#, i'm trying to work only using animation but random.

I have used 9 Ellipse in a grid, and my point is to change the color for the ellipse from white to blue just for a second or less then tern again to white, the ellipse will be chosen randomly or just to set the 9 Ellipse as invisible, then show them randomly, but with animation for seconds then hide.

how could I connect the animation as object and create random from the storyboard !

Here is my C# code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;

namespace Game
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void LayoutRoot_Loaded(object seander, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            Random rmd = new Random();

            mystory1.Begin();


        }



    }
}
```

and here is my xaml :

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
    x:Class="Game.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="480" d:DesignHeight="768"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="PortraitOrLandscape" Orientation="Portrait"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">


    <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

        <Storyboard x:Name="mystory1">

            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="El1"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
                            From="White" To="Blue"
                            Duration="0:0:2"
                            ></ColorAnimation>
        </Storyboard>

    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>


    <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent" Loaded="LayoutRoot_Loaded">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
        <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
            <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle" Text="MY APPLICATION" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle" Text="page name" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Ellipse Height="107" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Name="ellipse1" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120" >

                <Ellipse.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Name="El1" Color="White">


                    </SolidColorBrush>


                </Ellipse.Fill>

            </Ellipse>

            <Ellipse  Height="107" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Name="ellipse2" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120" Grid.Column="1" >

                <Ellipse.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Name="El2" Color="White">


                    </SolidColorBrush>


                </Ellipse.Fill>


            </Ellipse>

            <Ellipse  Height="107" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Name="ellipse3" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120" Grid.Column="2" >

                <Ellipse.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Name="El3" Color="White">


                    </SolidColorBrush>


                </Ellipse.Fill>

            </Ellipse>

            <Ellipse  Height="107" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Name="ellipse4" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120" Grid.Row="1" >

                <Ellipse.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Name="El4" Color="White">


                    </SolidColorBrush>


                </Ellipse.Fill>

            </Ellipse>

            <Ellipse  Height="107" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Name="ellipse5" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" >

                <Ellipse.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Name="El5" Color="White">


                    </SolidColorBrush>


                </Ellipse.Fill>

            </Ellipse>

            <Ellipse  Height="107" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Name="ellipse6" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" >

                <Ellipse.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Name="El6" Color="White">


                    </SolidColorBrush>


                </Ellipse.Fill>

            </Ellipse>

            <Ellipse  Height="107" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Name="ellipse7" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120" Grid.Row="2" >


                <Ellipse.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Name="El7" Color="White">


                    </SolidColorBrush>


                </Ellipse.Fill>

            </Ellipse>

            <Ellipse  Height="107" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Name="ellipse8" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" >

                <Ellipse.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Name="El8" Color="White">


                    </SolidColorBrush>


                </Ellipse.Fill>


            </Ellipse>

            <Ellipse  Height="107" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Name="ellipse9" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" >

                <Ellipse.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Name="El9" Color="White">


                    </SolidColorBrush>


                </Ellipse.Fill>

            </Ellipse>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>



</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

Comment: Do you want to accomplish all this in XAML with VisualState?  Or you don't mind a little Code-Behind?

Comment: @ChubosaurusSoftware , i don't mind with a little code for sure.:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a DispatchTimer to trigger a random selection and start the storyboard.  To get you started, you can take a look at this code.  If you run it, all it does is turn a random white circle to blue each second.  You will need to use the code as a reference and change it to meet your needs.

---

We need to change some XAML and name the ColorAnimation so:

In **App.xaml** put

```XAML
<!--Application Resources-->
<Application.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="mystory1">
        <ColorAnimation 
        x:Name="myColorAnimation"
        Storyboard.TargetName="El1"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" 
                    From="White" To="Blue"
                    Duration="0:0:2"
                    />
    </Storyboard>
</Application.Resources>
```

In **MainPage.xaml** put

```
<!-- add in the loaded event to the page to start the timer -->
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage Loaded="PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded">
```

---

**Namespaces**

```
using System.Windows.Threading;             // DispatchTimer
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;       // Storyboard
using System.Windows.Media;                 // Brushes
using System.Windows.Shapes;                // Shapes
```

**Create our DispatchTimer so it runs every XYZ second**

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    DispatcherTimer dt;
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // create our dispatch timer
        dt = new DispatcherTimer();
        dt.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        dt.Tick += dt_Tick;
    }

    // start the timer only when the page has loaded
    private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        dt.Start();
    }

    /// Every tick, generate a random number from 1 to 9.
    /// Use this number to find the Ellipse
    /// Set the Storyboard to this found Ellipse
    /// Start the Animation
    void dt_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {                       
        // generate a random number
        Random rmd = new Random();
        int random_int = rmd.Next(1, 9);

        Storyboard sb = (Storyboard)Application.Current.Resources["mystory1"];              // get the storyboard from Resources
        ColorAnimation ca = (ColorAnimation) sb.Children[0];                                // get the color animation

        sb.Stop();                                                                          // stop the storyboard to change the target name
        object myobject = this.FindName("El" + random_int.ToString());                      // setup the name based off the random number
        Storyboard.SetTarget(ca, (DependencyObject) myobject);                              // set the new target
        sb.Begin();                                                                         // start the animation

    }

}
```

---

Now you can add in a lot more Storyboard animations and have a mechanisms to target and start/stop to finish what you're trying to do.

[image: App]

Comment: when i run the code "ColorAnimation ca = (ColorAnimation)sb.Children[0];", its telling me "NullReferenceException"

Comment: i'm using 7.8 SDK, so when i implement as you said it gave me another error which is : "DataContext = App.ViewModel;" says that : Error 'Game.App' does not contain a definition for 'ViewModel'

Comment: 7.8 SDK? Ok.  Hmm.  Get rid of the DataContext line it's a generated lines for WP8.0 apps with the newest VS2013.  To solve the other problem you need to put the storyboard in App.xaml file. I will edit my solution.

Comment: There you go, I also tested on the WP7.8 emulator.  It should work if you did the changes, most importantly adding in the Storyboard in the App.xaml resources section.

Comment: if i need to detect on click while its blue , i'll need to use manipulationstarted , but how do i detect that depends on the time or the value if blue ? may you suggest ?

Comment: You can setup an Array with the state of each ellipse.  1 for on, 0 for off.  Remember in the Tick function we pick a random number.  All you have to do is before you pick a random number, clear all States to 0, after you pick a random number then turn that ellipse state to 1.  Now you will always know which ellipse is blue or not by accessing that array.

Comment: Well, I've been trying for the past hour.but it didn't work with me at all, may you give me a sample to work with detection state of the ellipse?Thanks :)

Comment: You're getting little bit into game design logic.  Here's a crappy code to show you.  It really should not be done this way, but it's a lot easier to understand then creating a Update() Draw() game loop.  Take look at : http://pastebin.com/Vm3RzDx7

Comment: Oh I forgot, you need to attach a tap event to each ellipse that goes to the Tap event that I pasted.